# Do I so often encounter simple past for past participle (e.g., “I have went,” “what was did to her”) because of where I am or when?

Tags: past-participles, simple-past, geography

Since moving to small-town northern Minnesota (USA) two dozen years back to teach English, I have noticed a lot of instances in spoken language where the simple past is used in lieu of the past participle, as in the examples listed above. Of course this is only noticeable or an issue for such irregular verbs as have two different forms for simple past and past participle. As a SCUBA diver, I encounter the perfect formation “have dove” with particular frequency.

Since I had no previous experience of living in northern Minnesota before 1990, and not much experience of living anywhere else since (except Greece), I cannot tell whether this usage is more a function of *where* I am as an observer of spoken English, or *when,* though I tend to suspect the former.

For those who are curious, my adopted small city was recently used as a fictional location for the TV miniseries spinoff of the Coen brothers’ film *Fargo,* but as with the film, the dialect in the miniseries is rather a caricature. (The show was not filmed here, and in representing Bemidji as a town *with* a strip club and *without* a library it was wrong on both counts.) The local dialect does show at least one notable Germanic influence: upon sighting a pretty infant, locals will exclaim “Oh for cute!”—which *for* I am pretty sure is more closely cognate with the German intensifying prefix *ver-* than with the English preposition. Other historically likely other-language influences, besides the Germanic Scandinavian languages, would include Finnish (Finno-Ugric), Ojibwe (Algonquian), and French.

N.B. Ngram is hard to read on this, since hits for “was did” might well be such as “What exactly it was, did not matter in the least,” and similarly for other word sequences.

Comment: Probly that's the case. Most areas of the US have special local usages like _might could, shoudn't oughta, so didn't I, he's a-lookin for you, that needs washed,_ etc. Especially in rural areas, and especially in areas with large swathes of non-English-speaking immigrants a century or so ago. That fits Minnesota just right.

Comment: @JohnLawler, yah, yewbetcha.

Comment: In Utah, it's yubetch. When I was teaching ESL at Utah State I used to get regular questions like "What mean you betch?", because it was the usual response to "Thank you" and I had very polite students.

Comment: @JohnLawler, if you had very impolite students you might need a different answer.

Comment: 'Polite students' might be considered a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Au contraire, @EdwinAshworth; I have had many a student here who was weirdly respectful and deferential at the very moment of my prevailing as accuser in a vainly appealed and (for the student) hugely consequential case of plagiarism.

Comment: @BrianDonovan "have dove" is an interesting example. Dictionaries seem to list "dove" as a valid, if unusual, past participle. Being from Ireland, "dove" just sounds wrong to me altogether - we use "dived" in both cases - but while I knew "dove" was used in the US I hadn't realized that "have dived" was still kept as the usual participle. Interesting.

Comment: @CupawnTae, the verb gives trouble in that people tend to think a regular past participle cannot be right for a verb that has an irregular, vowel-shifted simple past. I recall once in conversation someone I know ventured *diven* (short *i),* knowing and admitting that was wrong, but I had to admit it was a great try.

Comment: Perhaps because of where you are, but if so it's fairly local. It's not familiar from Moorhead, Brainerd, Ely, or the Greyhound bus that used to ply U.S. 10 between the Cities and Fargo. Is there any of it in early Dylan, before Hibbing's influence had faded?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Then there was Julia, an 80+-year-old roommate of mine in New York City. (I was in my early 20s, so there was no hanky panky going on.) When I thanked her for something, she would say, "No mench" (or mentch). I don't know how long I took to realize she was saying, "Don't mention it"! Don

Comment: Here in the UK, I get the impression that the old distinction between preterite and past participles is breaking down.  While educated speakers tend to keep to the old rules for common verbs [avoiding "I come" for "I came", and "I didn't took it" for "I didn't take it", for example], I've heard BBC presenters switching learned/learnt,  sprang/sprung, etc.

Comment: @DavidGarner: learned/learnt are just American/British alternatives of the past participle.

Comment: @user21820 you're right. I always thought (and thought I'd been taught) that pairs like learned/learnt were strictly preterite/perfect, but a quick check proves me wrong!

Comment: @David Garner: and the conjugations *spring/sprang/sprung*, *spring/sprung/sprung* are both in use. Hopefully, you didn't hear *has sprang*.

Comment: Although they were equally common before 1850, *sprung* is much less common now than *sprang* as a past tense; but strangely *sprung up* is still giving *sprang up* a run for its money. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+sprang+up%2C+I+sprung+up%2C+wind+sprang+up%2C+wind+sprung+up&year_start=1800&year_end=1850&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20sprang%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20sprung%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwind%20sprang%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwind%20sprung%20up%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Thanks, @PeterShor  I didn't hear *has sprang* but a US colleague, quite by coincidence, sent me 'an old American saying' [allegedly] : 'When you get to the dance you dance with who brung ya'.

Comment: @David Garner: That "old American saying" has bad grammar in order to make it appear "folksy". Other "old American sayings": "look what the cat drug in", "if it ain't broke, don't fix it",  "Lord willing and the creek don't rise". There seems to be some process in which sayings get "folksified" by introducing non-standard grammar.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterShor  I do hope you noticed the 'allegedly' in my comment.  As for "If it ain't broke, don't fix it", I'd say it's now embedded in international English. It's used a lot  -  in business, production and IT at least  -  here in England.

Comment: Do note that parts of northern Minnesota are quite isolated, from a linguistic point of view.  Many communities were strongly influenced by immigrants from (mainly) Scandinavia or Germany, and have not since "imported" influences from other cultures (aside from a relatively slow overall Americanization, and, of course, the influences of television).  Aside from the specific languages involved this is not unlike the situation in other relatively rural parts of the US.  Someone has probably studied the common "errors" in such dialects, but I'm not aware of where such studies would be found.

Comment: Re "Oh for cute" (or, more correctly, "Oh fer cute"), I regard that as "teen-speak" of the sort that is apt to attain currency among a group of young people.  Though the wording may have originated from a particular dialect, it is apt to be copied by unrelated youth cultures (and their "tuned in" older relatives), so the origin is lost.

Comment: Absolutely not @Hot Licks.  "Oh for cute" is used by all Minnesotans, no matter what age.  While I don't recall my family using "was did," they certainly say "He done" or "He don't."

Comment: @ewormuth - Well this Minnesotan doesn't use the expression.

Comment: @Hot Licks -- okay I shouldn't have said all.  Have you always lived there?  I just take issue with the notion that it's "teen-speak" -- much more likely, their older relatives.

Comment: @ewormuth - Lived here for 39 years, married to a woman from Fargo.  As to "Oh fer cute", I said teen speak *of a sort*.  From what little I've heard it I would guess that it was teen speak 40-50 years ago, but has aged with the (few) people who still use it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression of perfect aspect by combining a form of *have* with the simple past tense is not standard English usage.  They have been attested for centuries, however: they were noted and proscribed in some very early usage guides (e.g. *Reflections on the English Language* by Robert Baker, 1770; *A Grammatical Corrector* by Seth T. Hurd.  1847).

It is probably incorrect to label their usage illiterate, since they are widespread in the UK and the US as regional variants.  They should be avoided, however, in formal speech or writing.

Answer (score 0):

You should study the dialect of that region in detail. Perhaps there are already  studies. It seems an interesting object of study. The grammar seems simplified and the vocabulary seems to be strongly influenced by various other languages.

As to "Oh for cute" I am German, but "Oh for" doesn't remind me of anything in German. We would say something like "Oh wie schön/ niedlich" (Oh how cute).